# OFDM modulator in LTE

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, ifft

My understanding of what an OFDM modulator does, is that it takes a parallel sequence of QAM symbols of size M, pads it with zeroes corresponding to the zero subcarriers, then passes them through an IFFT block of same size M. IFFT is used because it can digitally create subcarriers.

My questions

1- Is the result output of the IFFT operation, an OFDM symbol of length M too?

2- Is EACH OFDM symbol going to be weighted sum of the ALL the QAM symbol?

3- How do things change if we have two antennas instead of one, do we have an OFDM modulator to each antenna? For example when using the Alamouti scheme? I have no clear vision how things change in this case, i.e what is the input at the IFFT now?

I am looking forward for answers thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. [Cyclic Prefix](http://www.lte-bullets.com/LTE%20in%20Bullets%20-%20Cyclic%20Prefix.pdf) and windows(prefix and postfix for pulse shaping) are added to the OFDM symbol, but windows are only for overlap-and-add for [pulse shaping](http://www.ieee802.org/3/bn/public/jan13/montreuil_01a_0113.pdf), so the effective length is M+CP_length only. I've mentioned Windowing since it is an important thing to take into consideration if you want to design and test an OFDM transmitter.
2. Each OFDM sample is the IFFT of the corresponding column of Resource Elements or in other words weighted sum of modulated subcarriers as @Serj put it.
3. A clear understanding of the sequence of codeword generation->Layer Mapping->Precoding is required to get big picture of LTE MIMO. [This](http://lteuniversity.com/get_trained/expert_opinion1/b/donhanley/archive/2011/09/20/codewords-and-layers-and-ports-oh-my.aspx) documents explains this sequence well. It's a little complicated as this trio-sequence is different for different channels(for example Layer Mapping and Precoding schemes for Broadcast channel and Shared or Data channel can be completely different within a single frame). If you want to know the finer details of this sequence you will have a take a look at [3GPP 36.211 spec](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/136200_136299/136211/10.00.00_60/ts_136211v100000p.pdf) from section 6.3.3 onwards. The following is the block diagram which depicts this sequence in a LTE transmitter.

[image]

Antennae Mapping depends on the [Transmission Mode](http://www.sharetechnote.com/html/Handbook_LTE_TransmissionMode.html) being used. The following table should give some clarity on this process.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Naveen, for your answer and for the references there in. I have questions regarding layer mapping, is it correct to say, that for transmit diversity there is ONE option available and that is ONE codeword and for spatial multiplexing there is only one option and it is TWO codewords? or can spatial multiplexing have one codeword? Also does precoding the step after the layer mapping, depends on the channel gain conditions? or are they fixed precoding matrices? Thanks

Comment: @Tyrone Yes, that is correct. The Transmit Diversity mode serves the purpose of making the transmission more robust my transmitting the same data stream(codeword) through multiple antennae ports. Spatial Multiplexing on the other hand is for increasing throughput, so multiple codewords(here it is 2 since that is the maximum number of allowed codewords) are mapped to multiple antennae ports. Only in case of closed loop spatial multiplexing the precoding matrices are changed based on PMI(Precoding Matrix Indicator) feedback from the UE.

Comment: cont..The PMI is related to the channel conditions and another UR feedback called Rank Index, but I'm not sure about the exact expression for calculating PMI.

Comment: thank you very much, so in transmit diversity, do you send DIFFERENT QAM symbols constituting the SAME codeword though multiple antenna OR do you send the same ONE symbol over the multiple antennas?@Naveen

Comment: cont.. so for example if we aim for transmit diversity with 4 layers, and we have a codeword: s0s1s3....... sm. Do you send s0 over layer 1 and s2 over layer 2 s3 over layer 3 and s4 over layer 4 and then repeat?

Comment: @Tyrone Yes, the above example is correct. Same codeword to multiple LAYERS(not antennas) with codeword symbols distributed to the layers in the same manner as in your example for transmit diversity.

Comment: @Naveen, thank you for your explanations. I'm wondering, is the same decoding scheme used for the Transmit Diversity and for the Spatial Multiplexing at the reciever side?

Comment: @Serj Encoding/Decoding schemes depends on the Channel, it's BER requirement and length of the message to be conveyed. For example Master Information Block(MIB) is a short Broadcast Channel message which carries very important info like Bandwidth, Frame Number, etc. so it is encoded with High redundancy with Tail-biting convolution codes. Shared Channel data on the other hand is much longer and BER requirement are not as stringent. Turbo coding is used for shared channel for increased code rate. So the TM modes do not influence the encoding/decoding scheme. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I mean spatial-time decoding for MIMO receiver, e.g. MMSE, ML or zero-forcing, no channel FEC decoding. If we use Transmitter Diversity it is some sort of STBC, am I right? While in the case of Spatial Multiplexing it can be V-BLAST or so on. So the question: is one hardware space-time decoder (or we can call it *space time equalizer*) used for both Transmitter Diversity and Spatial Multiplexing?

Comment: Do you mean to ask, what is the type of decoder used for spatial multiplexing purposed?@Serj

Comment: @Serj Sorry, lost tract of this thread. It should be possible to use one Equilizer for both Tx Diversity and Spatial Multiplexing since Equilization is done on layers(between tx and rx layers) after de-precoding(channel matrix multiplied by precoding matrix). I did not find any 3GPP spec which recommends specific equalizers for different transmission modes and channel conditions. I have worked on Matlab LTE systems toolbox where only ZF(for single Ant & TxDiv) and MMSE(SM & CDD) based equalizers are used. My guess it is it is left to the designed to decide on a suitable equalization technique.

Comment: @Tyrone, I mean space time decoder for both Tx Diveristy and Spatial Mux. It is computations greedy algorithm so I think it should be the same decoding for both schemes.

Comment: @Naveen, in ZF or MMSE we do MIMO channel matrix cancelation so knowing space time coding rule we can simply decode data after such processing. But they are suboptimal, what about ML (e.g. sphere decoding)? Do you know something about this approach application to jointly decoding of Tx Diversity and Spatial MUX?

Comment: @Naveen Hello Naveen, I was wondering if you can give me your opinion on my other question here. Thanks for everything http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/23648/general-questions-regarding-ofdm-modulation

Answer (score 4):

1. Definitely yes. But after IFFT operation data block is CP extended before transmission.
2. Each sample of OFDM symbol from the output of IFFT is weighted sum of all QAM/PSK modulated subcarriers from the input of IFFT.
3. In the MIMO case all spatial-time algorithms are applied in the frequency domain. So in transmitter you should do encoding with QAM subcarriers *before* IFFT and do the distinct IFFT for each spatial channel created. While in receiver you should do decoding *after* FFT applied separately to each spatial channel again. By doing this you exploit the fact OFDM is multiplexing of the large number (actually *M*) of narrow band channels and by appropriate processing (actually *FFT/IFFT pair and CP insertion technique*) we can treat each subcarrier as narrow band. It is very useful in the case of MIMO because MIMO decoding algorithms are much too simpler when dealing with narrow band (so *flat fading* channel is the case) and for each subcarrier we can define simple MIMO matrix of weights $[W_{ij}]$. That's why OFDM + MIMO is so popular combination today.